# I used pandas_datareader on YahooFinance

Tags: python, jupyter

I'd like to retrieve the market capitalization of CAC40 companies on yahoo finance.but I have a problem when I run the code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBEZE.png)

Here's the code I ranHere's the code I ran:

```
market_cap= get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['marketCap']
market_cap
```

I expected to get the market capitalization values of the 40 companies in the cac40

Comment: And what DO you get?  Do you have an account?  YahooFinance is now a subscription service.  https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/962

Comment: this is what I get:    RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=AI.PA&lang=en-US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance
Response Text:
b'{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","description":"Invalid Cookie"}}}'

Comment: "Unauthorized" -- that's the key word here.

Comment: I created an account a week ago but it's not very active yet

Comment: You didn't show us the code doing your authorization.  The problem must be there.

Answer (score 0):

List below only includes 5 stock tickers. Please add all companies from the list: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EFCHI/components/

Code:

```
from yahooquery import Ticker

cac40_tickers = ['BNP.PA', 'CAP.PA', 'DSY.PA', 'ENGI.PA', 'EL.PA']  # put all tickers in the list

myDict = Ticker(" ".join(cac40_tickers)).price

for ticker in cac40_tickers:
    ticker = str(ticker)
    market_cap = myDict[ticker]['marketCap']
    print(ticker, ":", market_cap, "€")
```

Output:

```
BNP.PA : 64385712128 €
CAP.PA : 29759438848 €
DSY.PA : 54772989952 €
ENGI.PA : 37575905280 €
EL.PA : 80267460608 €
```

You can check the market cap for BNP.PA: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BNP.PA?p=BNP.PA

```
Market Cap  64.386B
```